# Capturing frame of external swf and SecurityDomain

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Is there any way of capturing frame as a bitmap of swf loaded with different security domain than the main app?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `BitmapData`'s `draw(IDrawable)` function is straightforward if everything is in the same `SecurityDomain`.

Using this technique is only possible if the `SecurityDomain` of every loaded element that you're trying to render to accepts the domain of the code that is making the request (probably the domain of the swf).

Check out the docs for [BitmapData.draw(IDrawable)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29%20%22%20draw%28IDrawable%29). It says that it throws a `SecurityError` when:

> The source object and (in the case of a Sprite or MovieClip object)
>   all of its child objects do not come from the same domain as the
>   caller, or are not in a content that is accessible to the caller by
>   having called the Security.allowDomain() method. This restriction does
>   not apply to AIR content in the application security sandbox.

The upshot of this is that if you're using the standard `Loader` to load content from a domain that you do not control, you cannot create Bitmap "snapshots" of any DisplayObjectContainer that contains that content (unless it happens to allow access from all domains, or your domain explicitly). If you *do* control the domains, you should be able to make it work by using crossdomain.xml (for non-swf content) or `Security.allowDomain()` calls for swf content. The loaded swf must make the `allowDomain` call.

(As an aside, if you are just trying to get snapshots including static images from other domains, such as JPGs or GIFs, you can load the image data directly, and decode it into a Bitmap with an appropriate AS3 decoder (rather than using the standard `Loader`), which allows you to take bitmap snapshots of it.)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. 
However there is a workaround if you have access to any server side technology such as PHP where you deploy your swf. The fix is to use PHP to proxy the images for you. The PHP script loads the image using cUrl, and yuor swf is able to load them because they originate from the same domain.

Here is an example of a simple proxy script. In a production environment you should harden the script to prevent unauthorized users from accessing it.

```
<?php

$post_data = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;

$header[] = "Content-type: text/xml";
$header[] = "Content-length: ".strlen($post_data);

$ch = curl_init( $_GET['path'] ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

if ( strlen($post_data)>0 ){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
}

$response = curl_exec($ch);     
$response_headers = curl_getinfo($ch);     

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    print curl_error($ch);
} else {
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    header( 'Content-type: ' . $response_headers['content-type']);
    print $response;
}


?>
```